# use inherited classes as map Value

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods, dictionary

```
class StationSongs {
protected:
    int original_song; 
};

class NewsRadio: public StationSongs {
public:
    NewsRadio()
    {
        current_song = NULL;
        currently_empty = 0;
        original_song = 0;
        start_time_of_song = 0;
        next_song_to_play = NULL;
    }
};

class CommercialRadio : public StationSongs {
public:
    CommercialRadio() {
        current_song = NULL;
        currently_empty = 0;
        original_song = 0;
        start_time_of_song = 0;
        next_song_to_play = NULL;
    }
};
```

The problem : I want to use inherited classes as map Value

The map is:

```
typedef MtmMap<double, StationSongs*> RadioMap;


method{

    CommercialRadio new_station();

    RadioPair new_pair(stationFrequency,*new_station);

    radio.insert(new_pair);
}
```

I get This error :

```
Multiple markers at this line

- no matching function for call to 'mtm::MtmMap<double, mtm::StationSongs*>::Pair::Pair(double&, 

mtm::CommercialRadio 
     (&)())'
```

How can i Solve this ???

Comment: This really depends on the definition of `MtmMap` and type of `new_pair()`; these aren't standard classes and apparently come from a library you use (or your own code). Can you post them?

Comment: Can you remove the slew of extra asterisks please and all that? Those are significant operators in C++ and it could be that your problem is caused by that. Further, concerning the topic of your question, you can not use polymorphic types in any standard containers. Never. Really. The only thing you can do is to use pointers, which you got completely right. Now, even with the reduced readability, `CommercialRadio new_station();` is a function declaration, search for "C++ most vexing parse".

Answer (score 1):

`CommercialRadio new_station();` declares a function `new_station` that takes no arguments and returns a `CommercialRadio`. Remove the parentheses. This property of the C++ language is known as the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Furthermore, it’s almost certainly incorrect that your base class doesn’t define a virtual destructor.